# Autosys BOX job containing no CMDs

Tags: autosys

I am  new in my job and one of my responsibilities is to maintain a string of workload automation processes that run out of Autosys.  In browsing through the jobs, I noticed that some of them are `job_type: BOX` with no children of `job_type: CMD` within and no conditions either.  I can't figure the purpose of such a job.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few reasons:

One possible reason for this can be that the the children included jobs were decommissioned one by one but the box was never decommissioned.

Could be a place holder for future jobs that are to be put in later and are in design phase now.

Could be a coding error wherein the jobs that were to be included in the box got included in the main box.

Try running the following command to see the dependent jobs if any on your box.
job_depends -c -J box_name    if you do not get any dependent processes, you can verify if it is a place holder for a future job and if not, you can go ahead and delete it.
Hope this helps.